# How can I determine neighborhood from pairwise distance matrix efficiently?

Tags: pytorch

I have a M * N pairwise distance matrix between M points from group A and N points from group B.

I want to get the list of neighbor points from group B for each points from group A.

Is there any efficient code for this problem using pytorch? instead of multiple 'for' loop.

Thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to clarify your question, ideally with a small example. Also, please share any implementation (be it pseudocode or actual code) that you would use to brute-force your solution as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort`:

```py
import torch

# fake pairwise distance matrix, M=3, N=4
x = torch.rand((3,4))
print(x)
# tensor([[0.7667, 0.6847, 0.3779, 0.3007],
#         [0.9881, 0.9909, 0.3180, 0.5389],
#         [0.6341, 0.8095, 0.4214, 0.7216]])

closest = torch.sort(x, dim=-1)  # default is -1, but I prefer to be clear

# let's say you want the k=2 closest points
k=2
closest_k_values = closest[0][:, :k]
closest_k_indices = closest[1][:, :k]

print(closest_k_values)
# tensor([[0.3007, 0.3779],
#         [0.3180, 0.5389],
#         [0.4214, 0.6341]])

print(closest_k_indices)
# tensor([[3, 2],
#         [2, 3],
#         [2, 0]])
```